# APIPIE for a simple Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, documentation-generation, rails-api

I have a rails application (not rails-api)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
```

and not

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
```

I want HTML documentation for this app. I am using apipie for this purpose but I get

```
Oops!! Method <code></code> not found for resource <code></code>
```

The controllers are located at app/controllers/ and the configuration seems fine to me.

I am assuming that a rails application can also be treated as an API. The controllers are rendering json, should this be enough to treat the app as both a web app and an API ? Do I need to write a separate rails-api app for API purpose ? Help me understand the difference between the two, in case I am missing some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let me tell you about web app and app for API. You can keep both in one application. You need to use render as :json for API and render as html for web app. There is difference between both applications. Eventhough you can place both operations in one application but you need to be carefull about render/redirect.

For this error:

> Oops!! Method  not found for resource

You need to change your configuration in /config/initializers/apipie.rb

```
Apipie.configure do |config|
  config.app_name                = "AppDepot"
  # set api base url here
  config.api_base_url            = "/api/v1"
  # set url here for open docs related to apidoc
  config.doc_base_url            = "/apidocs"
  # set true/false for default validation
  config.validate                = false
  # set copyright here
  config.copyright               = "&copy; 2014 sachin"
  config.validate_value          = false

  # where is your API defined?
  config.api_controllers_matcher = "#{Rails.root}/app/controllers/api/v1/*.rb"
  config.default_version = "1.0"
  config.app_info = "Tell about your application"

  # set username and password for access api
  config.authenticate = Proc.new do
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      username == "admin@example.com" && password == "password"
    end
  end
end
```

Then restart your web server for get changes.